# Facebook not playing back my S3 MP4 video

Tags: html, facebook, video, amazon-s3, facebook-opengraph

A bit stumped about how to get Facebook to play back videos from my Amazon S3 bucket on a post. I.e. the user lands on my website page, clicks share and the shared post includes an embedded video.

Here is my og: markup on the web page:

```
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="<%= Rails.application.secrets.facebook_app_id %>"></meta>
     <meta property="og:site_name" content="<%=Rails.application.config.app_name %>"></meta>
     <meta property="og:url" content="<%= request.original_url %>"></meta>

     <meta property="og:title" content="I'm watching <%= @user.fb_name %> stream live"></meta>
     <meta property="og:description" content=<%= Rails.application.config.description %>></meta>

   <meta property="og:type" content="video"></meta>
     <meta property="og:video" content="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/tokbox-archives-01/45299372/9439f355-79ac-4c44-98eb-c71564efc4d5/test.mp4&autostart=true"></meta>
     <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/tokbox-archives-01/45299372/9439f355-79ac-4c44-98eb-c71564efc4d5/test.mp4&autostart=true"></meta>
     <meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4"></meta>
     <meta property="og:video:width" content="720"></meta>
     <meta property="og:video:height" content="1280"></meta>
      <meta property="og:image" content="<%= @user.fb_pic_uri%>"></meta>
```

Here is the video element on the page (not sure if required):

```
<video id="video_thing" src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/tokbox-archives-01/45299372/9439f355-79ac-4c44-98eb-c71564efc4d5/test.mp4" width="720px" height="1280px" autoplay></video>
```

Attached is the Facebook debugger information (2 images)
[image]
[image]

Finally, this last image is the screenshot of what shows up on the tester's Facebook feed: a video player is embedded, but it's black and the controls are disabled.
[image]

Look I'm sure there's a bunch of problems with the video (like the orientation, etc.) but right now my priority is to figure out why I can't embed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified the og:video URL as `https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/tokbox-archives-01/45299372/9439f355-79ac-4c44-98eb-c71564efc4d5/test.mp4&amp;autostart=true` – no matter if with `&amp;` or just `&`, that URL only gets a 404 response from S3. (Did you want to append a GET parameter here? The Query String of a URL *starts* with a question mark, not an ampersand.)

So you need to specify the *correct* URL to your video, which seems to be just https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/tokbox-archives-01/45299372/9439f355-79ac-4c44-98eb-c71564efc4d5/test.mp4

(You can add `?autostart=true` if you feel like it, but that won’t make any difference to Facebook – external videos can’t autoplay.)

Comment: OK you diagnosed it correctly. I had fixed a bunch of things but added these parameters for some reason.

Comment: do you have code for share S3 MP4 video to FACEBOOK?